# Applying JS onmouseover effect inside PHP

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

My problem is probably rather simple, but I'm not at that skill level yet. I'd like to apply a text-scrambling effect with jQuery on my H3's in my Wordpress sidebar. I found the H3 tags here (before_title and after_title):

```
register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => __( 'Main Sidebar', 'twentyeleven' ),
    'id' => 'sidebar-1',
    'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => "</aside>",
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title" >',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
) );
```

I tried adding `onmouseover='$("#unscramble").unscramble(); return false;'` in the opening h3 tag, but it broke my page, unsurprisingly. I'm not sure how I'd go about applying this effect anyway. The way it's arranged now, I suppose mousing over one trigger will trigger all h3s on the page, whereas I only want to trigger the current h3 I'm mousing over. I'm trying to use the 'unscramble' effect which can be found here at https://github.com/jaz303/jquery-grab-bag

Any help greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure you are applying the ID (`unscramble`) that you are selecting in your jQuery (the `$('#unscramble')`-part) to your `h3`s (although this would not work with more than one `h3`  so forget about this) **OR** select the element that triggers the function via `$(this)` (this is strongly preferred as you can use it with as many elements as you like).

Would read: `onmouseover='$(this).unscramble();'`
You can skip the `return false;` btw as this is not a link or something else with default mouseover behavior (at least that's what I think).

See those examples: http://jsfiddle.net/uZvYw/1/ and http://jsfiddle.net/uZvYw

Edit: As others have stated I too would think it would be a little better to generate this behavior in a seperate `<script>`, but that's just a side note

Comment: Sadly, it isn't working for me yet. I have this in my `head`:`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/alpha/js/jquery.text-effects.js"></script>`

and in my functions.php: `'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title" onmouseover=\'$(this).unscramble();\'>',
  'after_title' => '</h3>',`

Comment: Ahh... My script file was wrong. Now it is working. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try binding it elsewhere:

```
$("h3.widget-title").mouseover(function() {
    // do something
}).mouseout(function() {
    // do something else
});
```

Answer (score 1):

even though putting HTML or javascript code in PHP is not a good practice.
but did you escape the single quotes in mouseover?
like:

```
onmouseover=\'$("#unscramble").unscramble(); return false;\'
```

Comment: I figured that not escaping some characters was breaking my code, so thanks for that. I've responded to m90 with the code I have so far, but it's not working yet. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, it's working now, and you contributed, but I'm going to accept the 'this' answer. Thanks!